# sql selecting a lot of counts

Tags: mysql

I have a problem driving me nuts for the last 2 days. I basically have 4 tables with inheritance in the following order:

```
             users
               |
categories   blogs
     |      |     |
     ---- pages visits
```

So a user has many blogs which has many pages and visits. Each page also belongs to a category.

All I want is to extract all users with the following counts associated:

1. total number of blogs each user has
2. total number of pages each user has
3. total number of categories each user has blogs in
4. total number of visits each user has
5. total number of visitors each user has (visits but we count by distinct ip_address)

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    u.id
    u.username,
    COUNT(b.id) as blogs_count,
    COUNT(p.id) as pages_count,
    COUNT(v.id) as visits_count,
    COUNT(distinct ip_address) as visitors_count
    COUNT(c.id) as categories_count
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN
    blogs b ON(b.user_id=u.id)
LEFT JOIN
    pages p ON(p.blog_id=b.id)
LEFT JOIN
    visits v ON(v.blog_id=b.id)
LEFT JOIN
    categories c ON(v.category_id=c.id)
GROUP BY u.id, blogs_count, pages_count, visits_count, 
         visitors_count, categories_count
```

I should get 24 users with their counts but, given the fact that I have almost 300,000 visits I get my SQL database hanging in forever probably trying to pull millions of rows.
I'm not a db guru and it's obvious. Can someone point me to the right direction somehow so I can make a good query able to perform well on even millions of records (with the right hardware of course)?

Comment: Why do you have `categories` linking to `category_id` in the `visits` table? Shouldn't it be referencing the `pages` table?

Comment: You're right. A mistake sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT    u.id,
          u.username,
          COUNT(b.id)                     AS blogs_count,
          COALESCE(MAX(p.pagecnt), 0)     AS pages_count,
          COALESCE(MAX(v.visitscnt), 0)   AS visits_count,
          COALESCE(MAX(v.visitorscnt), 0) AS visitors_count,
          COALESCE(MAX(c.catcnt), 0)      AS categories_count
FROM      users u
LEFT JOIN blogs b ON u.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   blog_id, 
                   COUNT(*) AS pagecnt
          FROM     pages
          GROUP BY blog_id
          ) p ON b.id = p.blog_id
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   blog_id, 
                   COUNT(*) AS visitscnt, 
                   COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) AS visitorscnt
          FROM     visits
          GROUP BY blog_id
          ) v ON b.id = v.blog_id
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   aa.id,
                   COUNT(DISTINCT dd.id) AS catcnt
          FROM     users aa
          JOIN     blogs bb ON aa.id = bb.user_id
          JOIN     pages cc ON bb.id = cc.blog_id
          JOIN     categories dd ON cc.category_id = dd.id
          GROUP BY aa.id
          ) c ON u.id = c.id
GROUP BY  u.id, 
          u.username
```

---

### Breakdown

This should also work across different DBMSs like PGSQL, SQL-Server, etc.

The challenge is that you have this sort of hierarchy of 1:M relationships in which joining them all together can easily throw off the different types of counts (as you want distinct counts in some places, but total counts in others).

What I've decided to do is first subselect the count of each page and visit / distinct visitors, grouping by the `blog_id`. This ensures that we get only one row per `blog_id`, even after joining the subselects on the blogs table.

For the category count, you want a count of distinct categories per ***user***, but the challenge is that categories is linked deep within the relationship hierarchy (to the pages table), so you have to make a separate subselect that joins on the user_id instead of the blog_id.

Even with as many subselects as this query contains, it should still be quite fast as no two subselects are joining against each other. As long as there is an indexed table (subselects are actually unindexed temporary tables) on either side of the join, you should be fine.

Comment: Does the job pretty well. It's exactly what I needed. I'll have to digest it a little to understand 100% whats the logic behind it but thanks. Saved the day so far. I have a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    u.id
    u.username,
    COUNT(b.id) as blogs_count,
    COUNT(p.id) as pages_count,
    COUNT(v.id) as visits_count,
    COUNT(distinct ip_address) as visitors_count
    COUNT(c.id) as categories_count
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN
    blogs b ON(b.user_id=u.id)
LEFT JOIN
    pages p ON(p.blog_id=b.id)
LEFT JOIN
    visits v ON(v.blog_id=b.id)
LEFT JOIN
    categories c ON(v.category_id=c.id)
GROUP BY u.id
```

Try with removing blogs_count, pages_count, visits_count, visitors_count, categories_count from your group by statment.

Comment: I think that, if I decide to switch my application to a postgre db later on it will complain since I have to group by the selected fields. I'm still not decided on the database yet (mysql or postgre)